# ASP.Net MVC Custom Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to create a Logon System with ASP.NET MVC but not use the MembershipProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438151/is-it-possible-to-create-a-logon-system-with-asp-net-mvc-but-not-use-the-membersh)

I'm looking to create a custom authentication model for my MVC app but I'm not sure where to implement my custom IPrincipal and IIdentity classes. I don't want to do this in the Global.asax on every request as not all the pages in the site will need authentication. So my question is where? Should I be doing this in my custom action filters for the actions that require the user to be logged in?

I don't wish to use the Membership Provider or Forms Authentication this needs to be completely custom and separated.

Comment: This should have been kept open. The listed duplicate link covers authorization, but not authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a seperate base class for your controllers?

You can override the OnActionExecuting event to check to see if the user is authenticated... something like:

```
Public Class AuthenticatedPageController
    Inherits Controller

    Protected Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(ByVal filterContext As ActionExecutingContext)
    // Code to check user is authenticated - if not chuck them to the log in page...

    End Sub


End Class
```

Then, any controllers for pages where the user needs to be authenticated, inherit from this class instead of the standard controller class.

Comment: This is kind of what I want but when I check the current context user object I want it to be my implementation of the IPrincipal object and not the one created by default.