# Custom Authentication asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

At what point should I be checking for my cookie in my mvc app? Basically what I wish to do for each request is check to see if there is a cookie and if so show their name on the screen somewhere if not and the page requires the user to be logged in redirect them to a login page.

I DON'T want to use FormsAuthentication as I wish to create and use my own IPrinciple object I 'm just not sure whether I should be setting these in a base controller class or creating my own Authorize attribute and doing the checks in there.

My initial thoughts are that I should be doing this in the base controller class as this is similar to the base page in webforms where I override oninit.

Comment: You might want to see [ASP.Net MVC Custom Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1438151/148271)

Answer (score 3):

Do not attempt to do authentication in a base controller class. In a situation where an action result is cached, your action will not run at all, and no controller will ever be instantiated. Therefore, [authentication done inside the controller is broken by design](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/09/09/38390/).

The correct way to customize authentication, for many reasons, is to create a custom authentication provider. I've explained the reasons why and given links to simple examples of how to do this in the post linked above.

In short, using this method:

- Has the right level of modularity
- Works with caching
- Works with regular ASP.NET, as well as with MVC

Comment: Does creating my own provider handle creating the correct IPrincipal objects that are accessible via Context.User?
Also what about creating my own cookies and linking them in with this new provider?

Comment: You can do all of this in a custom provider, yes.

Comment: Whereabouts do I take care of all this, I have found examples of subclassing the membership provider but don't see any examples of where I would set up my cookies and create my own iprincpal objects, do you know of any examples of this.

Comment: You should not create cookies (you can, but you shouldn't). Cookies are encrypted. Most people (even experts) implement encryption incorrectly, so you should let the Membership system do this for you. You *should,* though, add the info you need in your cookies, either in Membership (if directly authentication related) or in Profiles (if not authentication related). There's a custom principal implementation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163807.aspx

Comment: "Cookies are encrypted" should probably read "the cookies created by Membership containing authentication tokens are encrypted," for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, can I ask what your thoughts are on handling this stuff in PostAuthenticateRequest like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal this

Comment: Because most people implement encryption incorrectly (even when using and off-the-shelf encryption tool), my general thought is that most developers should build off of existing systems rather than implement it themselves. In a quick skim, I don't see anything terribly wrong in that article, but I have not examined it in close detail, which is generally necessary when reviewing use of encryption. Nor have I examined in depth whether everything he is doing is actually necessary to customize, or whether off the shelf features could be used instead.