# Authenticating MVC users from Android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc

I just created my first MVC webapp and noticed that I need to store my users in the ASP Schema tables now.  I also have an Android app that must authenticate using the same list of users.

Before MVC, I was able to simply post something to a webform and have it check the list of usernames and password for a match (encrypted of course), then the form would return the requested info.  How would I do this using MVC?

Otherwise, could I just change MVC's authentication to use my own user tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store your user details in default ASP schema tables. You can create custom [membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx) or you can do it [without custom membership provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438151/is-it-possible-to-create-a-logon-system-with-asp-net-mvc-but-not-use-the-members) as well.

You can still POST to your controller action the same information and continue to execute the same logic you were using.